# No PSVM() Method in an activity.?

Tags: android

I am totally new in Android World. Android Works on java technology.
    so why there is no use of Public static void main() method at all.????
    Instead Intents are use to activate the required components..
Thanks

Comment: instead of public static void main here they are extending activity

Comment: ok.. but is it something to do with android code reusability feature,as there are multiple Entry points to enter into an application(via through components) to access them..???

Comment: Look at this...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099640/main-loop-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Public static void main() is not required in the program.
Reason being whenever the application is launched, manifest file is red first where Which Activity to be launched first is mentioned(which is the entry point to the application).
And the flow of execution is UI basis thereafter, that is onCreate() or onStart() etc executes depending upon the activity states.